# How to access nested object in javascript using foreach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, foreach, vuejs2

Well, this is my response. `results` is a new empty array. `address` is my nested object in user

```
response.data.forEach(user => {
          results.push({
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            address: user.address.number
          })
        })
```

This way I get undefined result from address object. So how can I access it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing some sample data but from the look of it, I would guess `user.address.number` is simply not defined in your data set.  Why would you expect it is?

By the way, your combination of `forEach` and `push` could be simplified with `map`:

```
var results = response.data.map(user => ({
  id: user.id,
  name: user.name,
  address: user.address.number
}));
```